# How to post Integer in Alamofire Parameters

Tags: swift, http-post, alamofire

i followed a tutorial for Register and Login Request in xcode.
But i have a problem with the Code because i changed some values of it.
My variables in the php script are ssiss (string, string, int, string, string). In the swift file i am using Alamofire. Here it is:

```
 @IBAction func buttonRegister(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let ageINT = Int(ageTF.text!);


    //creating parameters for the post request
    let parameters: Parameters=[
        "name":nameTF.text!,
        "username":usernameTF.text!,
        "age": ageINT ?? 0,
        "country":countryTF.text!,
        "password":passwordTF.text!,
    ]

    //Sending http post request
    Alamofire.request(URL_USER_REGISTER, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON
        {
            response in
            //printing response
            print(response)

            //getting the json value from the server
            if let result = response.result.value {

                //converting it as NSDictionary
                let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary

                //displaying the message in label
                self.labelMessage.text = jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as! String?
            }
    }
```

I think the problem is i pass an String value instead of a integer value. That is why i already have changed the value for **"age"** from **"age":ageTF.text!,** to **"age": ageINT ?? 0,**

The error i am get is "Required parameters are missing".

I am getting this "error-response" message because of this php-script:

```
<?php

 //importing required script
 require_once '../includes/DbOperation.php';

 $response = array();

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if (!verifyRequiredParams(array('name', 'username', 'age', 'country',       'password'))) {
    //getting values
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $country = $_POST["country"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    //creating db operation object
    $db = new DbOperation();

    //adding user to database
    $result = $db->createUser($name, $username, $age, $country, $password);

    //making the response accordingly
    if ($result == USER_CREATED) {
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['message'] = 'User created successfully';
    } elseif ($result == USER_ALREADY_EXIST) {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'User already exist';
    } elseif ($result == USER_NOT_CREATED) {
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = 'Some error occurred';
    }
} else {
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Required parameters are missing';
}
 } else {
$response['error'] = true;
$response['message'] = 'Invalid request';
}

//function to validate the required parameter in request
 function verifyRequiredParams($required_fields)
 {

//Getting the request parameters
$request_params = $_REQUEST;

//Looping through all the parameters
foreach ($required_fields as $field) {
    //if any requred parameter is missing
    if (!isset($request_params[$field]) || strlen(trim($request_params[$field])) <= 0) {

        //returning true;
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
}

print_r(json_encode($response));
 ?>
```

And this is the other php script:

```
<?php

class DbOperation
{
    private $conn;

    //Constructor
    function __construct()
    {
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Constants.php';
        require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/DbConnect.php';
        // opening db connection
        $db = new DbConnect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();
    }

    //Function to create a new user
    public function createUser($name, $username, $age, $country, $password)
    {
        if (!$this->isUserExist($username)) {
            $password = md5($pass);
            $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name, username, age, country, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("ssiss", $name, $username, $age, $country, $password);
            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                return USER_CREATED;
            } else {
                return USER_NOT_CREATED;
            }
        } else {
            return USER_ALREADY_EXIST;
        }
    }


    private function isUserExist($username)
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = ? ");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0;
    }
    }
```

Comment: Pease add output this variable  `parameters` and log this `$result`

Comment: How do i do this?

Comment: Simply add `print(parameters)` before sending http post request. If you have a value equal to "", you have your answer :)

Comment: Thank you. But it is weird because now he prints me: **["password": "12345", "name": "aaaa", "age": 21, "username": "aaaa", "country": "Germany"]** It is a complet different order. Why is that?

Comment: and `echo $result`

Comment: You should never depend on the order of the elements of a hash/dictionary except if the language _explicitly_ states it keeps the order invariant (as ruby does for instance). Since Swift wants to be as fast as possible it does not guarantee the order of elements in a `Dictionary` and this is the _right thing_ to do. Your set of `keys` will be complete though. _That_ is what you should depend on on the server side.

Comment: You should provide the user with a message that tells him which parameter is missing, otherwise it is just guesswork for him (you). If you want to keep things secret you should at least log the missing field on the server, that way _you_ will have more information.